# java: command not found in cygwin bash

Tags: bash, java, cygwin

I'm trying to run a series of programs in Cygwin.

My current dilemma is running a java file.  My input and the error is below.

```
Gaius@Ellislab2015 ~/muTect-1.1.4-bin
$ java -jar muTect-1.1.4.jar
-bash: java: command not found
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### -bash: java: command not found

You need to add Java to your bash `PATH` variable.

This is normally done by editing the appropriate lines in `~/.bash_profile`.

```
# User dependent .bash_profile file

...

# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How can I set my Cygwin PATH to find javac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918830/how-can-i-set-my-cygwin-path-to-find-javac?rq=1)
- [64 Bit Java Path in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238317/64-bit-java-path-in-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my file in home/.bash_profile  (~/.bash_profile), as suggested by DavidPostill, and after looking at documents he referenced:

Before:

```
# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi
```

After:

```
# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
# PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/:${PATH}
# fi
```